# Conditions on Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, switch-statement, fragment

I have an activity witch have switch case and I also have two different fragments. I want when I click on a button a fragment is add/replace on that activity and when I click another button another fragment add/replace on that activity.
What I should do?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
             case R.id.button1:
                Intent intentFaculty = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FacultyLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentFaculty);
                break;
             case R.id.button2:
            Intent intentAdmin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminLoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentAdmin);
            break;
    }
}
```

Instead of start activity I want to add fragments.

Comment: public void onClick(View view) {
               switch (view.getId()){
                  case R.id.button1:
                       Intent intentFaculty = new Intent(MainActivity.this,   FacultyLoginActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intentFaculty);
                       break;
                   case R.id.button2:
                       Intent intentAdmin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminLoginActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intentAdmin);
                 break;
        }
    }    instead of start activity I want to add a fragment.

Comment: Do you need any more help? Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Okay I got it....Thank you @bendaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface in your fragment like:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener{
    void onClick(int buttonId);
}
```

Implement your interface in your activity:

```
@Override 
public void onClick(int buttonId){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if(index == R.id.btn_change_fra){
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("FragmentChange");
        newFragment = new NextFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, newFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Override onAttach in your fragment:

```
OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
@Override public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener){
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    }else{
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                                           + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

And finally call the onClick() method in onClick:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   mListener.onClick(view.getId());
}
```

That's it. I suggest you to use more unique names.